# Chaining multiple classes in a MVC4 view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ef-code-first

Let's say I have a model like this (simplified from the original):

```
public class Location
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string BinNumber { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Bin { get; set; }
}

public class LineOnPickList
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Item Item { get; set; }
}
```

The usual thing to do here on the LineOfPickList Create view would be to have a dropdownlist that listed all the Item Descriptions and put the selected item in the newly created LineOnPickList record when Create was clicked.

What I need to do however is show a dropdownlist of Location BinNumbers, yet still have the Item associated with that Location in the newly created LineOnPickList record.

How would that be done?

Comment: How does `Item` relate to `Location`?

Comment: Oops... I defined the Item class wrong. Corrected now...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a view model for your drop down

```
public class ItemViewModel
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string BinNumber { get; set; }
}
```

Then build the drop down list data in your controller action as follows

```
public class CreateLineOnPickListViewModel
{
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ItemViewModel> Items { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new CreateLineOnPickListViewModel();
    model.Items = db.Items
          .Select(i => new ItemViewModel { ID = i.ID, BinNumber = i.Bin.BinNumber });

    return View(model);
}
```

Then in your view

```
@model CreateLineOnPickListViewModel

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ItemId, new SelectList(Model.Items, "ID", "BinNumber"), "-")
```

Then your post action method in your controller would look like this

```
public ActionResult Create(CreateLineOnPickListViewModel model)
{
    var item = new Item { ID = model.ItemID };
    db.Items.Attach(item);

    var lineOnPickList = new LineOnPickList { Item = item };

    db.SaveChanges();

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to access `model` inside of a controller. Please tell me how that is done.

Comment: I must be missing a reference in my view, it doesn't see CreateLineOnPickListViewModel as a valid choice for @model unless I put the definition for `class CreateLineOnPickListViewModel` in my model file.     Where in the view do I put `public ActionResult Create(...`?

Comment: @davecove place the `CreateLineOnPickListViewModel` class in your `Models` folder. Give the class name with the namespaces when you define the `@model` in your view. `public ActionResult Create(` part should go into your controller. Sorry about that.

Comment: Ok, I replaced my existing `[HttpPost] ActionResult Create` with this one, and while my BinNumbers are showing up in the DropDownList on my view, and I am able to pick one, and model.Items returned to `ActionResult Create` has one element in it, that one element is always null. Its like the details of my DropDownList choice are not being included with the post back to `ActionResult Create`.

Comment: @davecove Yes. Those values will not be posted back. The selected option value is populated to `ItemID` property.